# how to include the license fie in the wheel with Hatch?

Tags: python, setuptools, hatch

In setuptools I was used to do the following:

```ini
[tool.setuptools]
license-files = ["LICENSE.txt"]
```

How can I do the same using hatch ?

Comment: Hatch's documentation is surprising wanting. If you're flexible about your build system, this is trivial to do in [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/), which is comparatively more feature rich and much better documentation.